# about_Parsing documentation

Tags: powershell

I'm a little confused with the official documentation about [parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-6).

It starts by introducing the 2 parsing modes: expression and argument (which I believe is also known as command). In the argument mode, it says that:

> In argument mode, each value is treated as an expandable string unless it begins with one of the following special characters: dollar sign (`$`), at sign (`@`), single quotation mark (`'`), double quotation mark (`"`), or an opening parenthesis (`(`). If preceded by one of these characters, the value is treated as a value expression.

And then it presents a neat table with several examples.

[image: Examples of commands processed in expression and argument mode]

The last entry on the table makes me wonder about the previous rules. Shouldn't the argument of the `Write-Output` cmdlet be interpreted as an expression since it starts with the `$` special character?

I've noticed that If I only write the expression `$a/H` then it will try to interpret it as an expression (returning an error because there's no `H`, but when used in the context of the cmdlet, it will be parsed as a string.

Can someone help with the interpretation of the parsing modes?